# Почему я не могу авторизоваться сразу после регистрации?

Tags: django

Новый пользователь записываеться в базу, но не авторизуеться.Я получаю ошибку "*'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_met*".

*forms.py*

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,   widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'E-mail'}))


class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username']

def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    try:
        User.objects.get(email=email)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return email
    raise forms.ValidationError('email already exist')

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.username = self.cleaned_data['email']
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    if commit:
        user.is_active = False
    user.save()
    return user
```

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import auth
from .forms import RegistrationForm

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            # user.set_password()
            user =   auth.authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data.get('username'), password=form.cleaned_data.get('password1'))
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'fighter/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Python3.5 and Django1.10

Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/register/

Django Version: 1.10.6
Python Version: 3.5.2

Traceback:

File "/home/google/.virtualenvs/master/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  42.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/google/.virtualenvs/master/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/google/.virtualenvs/master/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/google/webapp/englishfighter/fighter/views.py" in register
  27.             auth.login(request, user)

File "/home/google/.virtualenvs/master/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/**init**.py" in login
  124.     request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)

File "/home/google/.virtualenvs/master/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in inner
  235.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /register/
Exception Value: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста трейсбек ошибки. Например, должно быть не `_met`, а `_meta`, если я правильно понимаю ошибку.

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняли, я не до конца скопировал.

Answer (score 1):

Следующие строки:

```
auth.login(request, user)
return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile')
```

должны входить в блок `if form.is_valid():`